# Mouseenter/mouseleave multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter

I have three divs in a line going down a page with classes e.g. .class1, .class2, .class3.

when a users mouse enters either of the divs i want to show other divs (divA & divB), question is can i have multiple divs in the function?

this is what I have so far, for one div which works great:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".class1", function ()
{
$(this).children(".divA").slideDown();
$(this).children(".divB").slideDown();
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", ".class1", function ()
{
$(this).children(".divA").slideUp();
$(this).children(".divB").slideUp();
});
});
```

I want the effect to happen though if a use enters either .class1, .class2 or .class3

Without a similar function three times

I've tried .class1 && .class2 etc but no joy, also .class1 || .class2 etc but also no joy

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery you can separate selectors with `,` so in your case something like `".class1, .class2"` and so forth.

jQuery will then look for elements that match one or multiple of those selectors.

**Update:**

You can shorten the code a bit by binding both the events to the same callback, and use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead:

```
$(function() {
   $("body").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".class1, .class2, .class3", function ()
   {
       $(this).children(".divA, .divB").slideToggle();
   });
});
```

*Haven't tried it, but this should be equivalent to your code in terms of functionality. Just a bit shorter.*

Comment: @DarrenSweeney The beauty of jQuery ;)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney See my updated answer, where I've simplified your code a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".class1, .class2, .class3", function ()
{
$(this).children(".divA").slideDown();
$(this).children(".divB").slideDown();
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", ".class1, .class2, .class3", function ()
{
$(this).children(".divA").slideUp();
$(this).children(".divB").slideUp();
});
});
```